# Is there a standard way to get atomic changes or actions performed on a text area or input?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get atomic changes performed on a textarea.

These changes might be:

- Pressed 'z' at selectionstart 45
- Pressed delete at selectionstart 46 until selectionend 50

I've tried plugging into the `onInput` and `onKeyUp` methods, but these don't seem to have *where* the actions took place.

Comment: What do you mean by *atomic changes* exactly? What do the numbers 45, 46 and 50 mean in your example, are they the string indexes?

Comment: The location of the cursor on the textarea. I'm building a list of "actions done on this textarea", so I need cursor locations.